# Knockout not displaying data in mvc view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I am using knockout in MVC 4 web application. Knockout does not render any data where as the controller method is returning data. There are no errors in the console too.
The property names in view also matches with the names of properties in model class.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetUsers()
    {
        using (UsersContext context = new UsersContext())
        {
            return Json(context.UserProfiles.ToList(),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }

    <script type="text/javascript">

       function users() {

       var vm = this;

       vm.registeredUsers = ko.observableArray();

       $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetUsers", "Account")',
        cache: false,
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {
          vm.registeredUsers(data);
        }
     });

    }

    var usersViewModel = new users();
    ko.applyBindings(usersViewModel);

  </script>

<tbody data-bind="foreach: registeredUsers">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: UserId"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: UserName"></td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

The model class:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    public UserProfile();

    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show your `UserProfile` class.

Comment: exlude the ajax function from your users() function -. and do some debugging like console log, in foreach try to first use text:$data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should change these 2 things:

1) the script should run on domready (ie put it inside

```
$(function(){
   //your script here
});
```

3) Finally,

```
 ko.applyBindings(usersViewModel);
```

should have as a second parameter the DOM element where to apply the binding, ie:

```
 ko.applyBindings(usersViewModel, $('table-selector')[0]);
```

Edit: looks like this is optional and ko will bind to the whole of the [document] if no dom element is  specified)

Comment: Just after doing what you specified in point 1, the code started working. Thanks.